# Unable to use the google.cloud.sql.connector module in Google composer

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to schedule a dataflow pipeline job to read content from a CloudSQL SQLServer instance and write it to the BigQuery table. I'm using the google.cloud.sql.connector[pytds] for setting connection. The manual dataflow job runs successfully when I run it through the Google cloud shell. The airflow version(using Google cloud composer) fails, giving Name error.
'NameError: name 'Connector' is not defined'

I have enabled the save-main-session option. Also, I have mentioned the connector module in the py_requirements option and it is being installed(as per the airflow logs).
py_requirements=['apache-beam[gcp]==2.41.0','cloud-sql-python-connector[pytds]==0.6.1','pyodbc==4.0.34','SQLAlchemy==1.4.41','pymssql==2.2.5','sqlalchemy-pytds==0.3.4','pylint==2.15.4']

[2022-11-02 07:40:53,308] {process_utils.py:173} INFO - Collecting cloud-sql-python-connector[pytds]==0.6.1
[2022-11-02 07:40:53,333] {process_utils.py:173} INFO -   Using cached cloud_sql_python_connector-0.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)

But it seems the import is not working.

Comment: Could you post the code where the `Connector` is imported and used?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the `PyPi` packages in `Cloud Composer` nodes, you have a `tab` in the `GUI` and `Composer` page :

[image]

Add all the needed packages for your `Dataflow` job in `Composer` via this page, except `Apache Beam` and `Apache Beam GCP` because `Beam` and `Google Cloud` dependencies are already installed in `Cloud Composer`.

`Cloud Composer` is the runner of your `Dataflow` job and the runner will instantiate the job. To be able to instantiate the job correctly, the runner needs to have the dependencies installed.

Then the `Dataflow` job in execution mode, will use the given `py_requirements` or `setup.py` file in the workers.

`py_requirements` or `setup.py` must also contains the needed `Packages` to execute the `Dataflow` job.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response!!. In addition to the py_requirements option in the dag file, I added the following pipeline options in the dataflow file which seemed to fix the issue. pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).requirements_file = '/home/airflow/gcs/dags/requirement.txt'                                                                                                 I think I could have done the same thing through the GUI, by following your suggestion. Are these doing the same thing?

Comment: Yes for the Dataflow job, the packages can be bring by setup py file or requirements.txt. But you must also add the same packages in Composer (PyPi packages).